# Meaning of "they inflicted serious injuries on three other men"

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Meaning of "they inflicted serious injuries on three other men".

I understood like this "they beated three persons".

Comment: For future reference, in addition to the answer below, the past tense of "beat" is just "beat," not "beated," and the plural of "person" is usually "people," so the correct way to phrase your sentence is "They beat three people."

Comment: @Kevin Anderson Thank you for correcting my sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means they caused injuries to them. It doesn't say how. They may have beat them, hit them with a car, stabbed them, or something else. All we know is that there are injuries, and they aren't just light bruises.

A serious injury is normally something you have to go to the hospital for. The image that is conveyed is someone getting stitches for a laceration, but it could mean broken bones, serious bruises, a concussion, or something like a lost limb. Whatever the injuries are, it will be some time before a full recovery is made and likely there will be permanent effects.